# Adjust zoom-based styling elements in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to customize a Google Maps style by adjusting parameters with Google Maps Styling tool: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com

One particular style I'm trying to achieve is to have the wooden areas (in green on the top image) displayed no matter what level of zooming users choose. For instance, wooden areas are displayed at the zoom level of the top image, and disappear at the next zooming increment in the bottom image.

Is there a styling parameter to keep these elements displayed no matter the zooming level?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, there isn't. All the parameters adjust the display of the elements (there or not, if visible, color/style), they don't change the behavior on zoom.  You can do that by hiding the feature then displaying it yourself based on the zoom level.